# ToDo List NodeJs -CSS file Not Linked

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am Creating Todo List using nodeJs but I am not able to link CSS file.
I have linked in CSS file in header.ejs and then included it in list.ejs file.
but still CSS file is not linked.

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the best way to go about it.
You need to create a public folder in your root app. Then you create a css folder as well, then you can now create any css file inside. So you should have something like this

```
public > css > file.css
```

So you move on to your app.js file and add this

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
```

Once you've done all that, you can now add your css to any ejs file.
For example

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
```

Comment: Alright. Weldone.